# buttons 2.4.1 css differs between standalone and builder package

Tags: jquery, datatables, jquery-plugins

When I don't download the [standalone version](https://datatables.net/download/release#Buttons) of the buttons css   then the layout is broken:

[image]

I am using the [DataTables download builder](https://datatables.net/download/) which creates this long `css` link:

```
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs5/jq-3.7.0/jszip-3.10.1/dt-1.13.5/af-2.6.0/b-2.4.1/b-colvis-2.4.1/
  b-html5-2.4.1/b-print-2.4.1/cr-1.7.0/date-1.5.1/fc-4.3.0/fh-3.4.0/kt-2.10.0/
  r-2.5.0/rg-1.4.0/rr-1.4.1/sc-2.2.0/sb-1.5.0/sp-2.2.0/sl-1.7.0/sr-1.3.0/
  datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Here is a clickable [version](https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs5/jq-3.7.0/jszip-3.10.1/dt-1.13.5/af-2.6.0/b-2.4.1/b-colvis-2.4.1/b-html5-2.4.1/b-print-2.4.1/cr-1.7.0/date-1.5.1/fc-4.3.0/fh-3.4.0/kt-2.10.0/r-2.5.0/rg-1.4.0/rr-1.4.1/sc-2.2.0/sb-1.5.0/sp-2.2.0/sl-1.7.0/sr-1.3.0/datatables.min.css).

Loading the standalone version BEFORE or AFTER the above long CSS link produces the correct layout:

[image]

The [`collectionLayout`](https://datatables.net/reference/button/collection) attribute is shown correctly [`'two-column'`].

---

***So, my question is, what am I doing wrong that I have to include the buttons css separately and the builder version doesn't seem to work correctly.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug and after I posted it in the DataTables forum [Allan from DataTables fixed it](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/76846/buttons-2-4-1-css-differs-between-standalone-and-builder-package/).